# WPF ComboBox editing text AutoCompletion

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a ComboBox that contains a list of words. Some of them are abbrivations consisting of capital letters.
Let's assume you have the following words in the list:

```
... other words
CA
... other words
```

When you type the c (lowercase) the ComboBox makes the c uppercase and displays a selected capital A afterwards.
When you continue typing "ar" the text in the ComboBox results in "CAr" though you typed "car" (all lowercase). The word "car" is not a member of the list.
Is there a way to get the WinForms ComboBox' behaviour or at lease make sure that the uppercase/lowercase is preserved for words that are not part of the attached word list.

Comment: Are you asking about the WPF ComboBox or the WinForms ComboBox, because they are two very different things, but you mention WPF in the title and WinForms in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can set

```
<ComboBox IsTextSearchCaseSensitive="True" />
```

to enable context-sensitive searching which preserves the case of the letters.

Comment: It's not the thing that I want case sensitive search. Case insensitv search is fine and intended, but I don't want that small letter become capital letters and vice versa. If you have an abbivation with capital letters and you want to input a word with the same starting letters as the abbivation, the ComboBox makes the matching character uppercase although I typed the word in small leters. The question is, how to make sure that the upper/lower case is not altered by existing words in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Very late to the party.
`ShouldPreserveUserEnteredPrefixProperty` will prevent the combobox autocomplete changing the case of the text you've already entered :)

It only works when `IsTextSearchCaseSensitive`=`false`.